# Facebook SDK crashes iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

My app was working as intended and completely fine before adding the Facebook SDK but i added it as it is a requirement for a new use case.

This is how my story goes:

I downloaded the SDK from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-ios-sdk-3.2.pkg), dragged the framework bundle into the frameworks folder of my XCode project, then dragged the bundle files from the Facebook framework into the Frameworks folder of my XCode project. Afterwards, i added the AdSupport, Accounts and Social frameworks and the libsqlite3.dylib and libsqlite3.0.dylib files to the libraries to link list.

Now the problem is that when i try to open my app on the iOS simulator, the app opening animation (The one which zooms the drawer into the app) starts and is hastily canceled back into the drawer. And i have no logs on XCode.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a linker error , like there is blah blah slice missing for Facebook sdk ?

Comment: Sorry i did not close this, i solved it with more googling and re-doing the project.

Comment: It is still not closed